# How to continuously mirror/duplicate data from one collection into another database in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'll try to explain the use case the best I can.

Today we have **one** MongoDB database to store all our application data. Soon we will split that into **two** separate databases (this is a hard requirement).

Today we have several MongoDB charts that uses aggregations including collections that will soon be located in the two separated databases. This will break the charts since you can't do "joins" between databases.

My idea is to merge the two databases into a third one that looks exactly like the one we have today. Then the charts should be able to work without any required changes if they target that merged database. Since it is charts the requirement on them being real time is not crucial. It is fine that the data "eventually get there".

We will never mutate the data in the merged database. The only goal here is to mirror the data from **collection A in the first database** and **collection B in the second database** so that we end up with **collection A and B in the third database**.

We run everything in MongoDB Atlas.

All manual options are not acceptable. It has to be automated and it has to be somewhat close to real time (a matter of seconds rather than minutes).

I have briefly looked into the documentation of tools like `mongomirror` and `mongosync` but they seem to be more manual fashion and not suitable.

What are my options? What tools within MongoDB are at my hands? Are there solutions outside of MongoDB that could work with little effort?

Comment: I can't say that I'm super clear on the hard requirement of splitting the data into two databases, particularly since this question is effectively asking about undoing that. But in any case, I separately have a question about your comment about `mongosync`. That utility, which is the thing powering ['Cluster-to-Cluster Sync'](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cluster-to-cluster-sync/current/quickstart/) seems to be designed basically for your exact use case. Can you describe a little bit more about what makes them 'more manual and not suitable' for your use? Hard to suggest alternatives otherwise

Comment: Well. I won't go into details about the use case sorry. But I think I was a bit quick to rule out `mongosync`. At first glance I thought it was a one time operation but it clearly states that it "provides continuous data synchronization" as well. Thanks for pointing me to `mongosync` again. Cluster to cluster is nice but it might not be necessary. Source and destination cluster could point to the same one. And in combination with [filtered sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cluster-to-cluster-sync/current/reference/collection-level-filtering/) it might actually provide the tooling I need.

Comment: Thinking about it some more. I need to sync `collection1` from `dbA` and `collection2` from `dbB` into a result where `dbC` in the destination cluster contains both `collection1` and `collection2`. I wonder if that is possible. My interpretation is that `mongosync` would only sync so that I still end up with `dbA` and `dbB` at the destination. There is no way to merge them together easily. What do you think?

Comment: At first glance [this looks like a viable option](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/query-multiple-databases-with-atlas-data-federation/). It seems to solve the exact problem I have by merging two databases virtually.